# HTTP Status 404 - /FitnessTracker/delete/1

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

I'm working on **Spring MVC + Hibernate + JSP** example. In this example I've developed below screen and delete button which I want to delete the populated record.

[image]

When I'm clicking on delete link, its says HTTP Status 404 - /FitnessTracker/delete/1. I am really not understanding what is wrong here.

**MinutesController.java**

```
@Controller
public class MinutesController {

    @Autowired
    private ExerciseService exerciseService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addMinutes",  method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getMinutes(@ModelAttribute ("exercise") Exercise exercise, ModelMap model) {
        List<Exercise> exercises = exerciseService.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("exercises", exercises);

        return "addMinutes";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addMinutes",  method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addMinutes(@Valid @ModelAttribute ("exercise") Exercise exercise, BindingResult result, ModelMap model ) {

        // check if there are any errors
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return "addMinutes";
        }

        // save the new Exercise
        exerciseService.save(exercise);

        // return all saved exercises
        List<Exercise> exercises = exerciseService.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("exercises", exercises);

        return "addMinutes";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/activities", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Activity> findAllActivities() {
        return exerciseService.findAllActivities();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete/{exerciseId}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String deleteActivity(@PathVariable("exerciseId") Long exerciseId) {

        exerciseService.deleteExercise(exerciseId);

        return "redirect:/activities";
    }
}
```

**addMinutes.jsp**

```
        <form:form commandName="exercise">
            <form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div" />

                <h4>View All Exercises</h4>
                <table align="left" border="1" cellpadding="10">
                    <tr>
                        <th><b>Minutes</b></th>
                        <th><b>Activity</b></th>
                        <th><b>Delete</b></th>
                    </tr>
                    <c:forEach var="exercise" items="${exercises}">
                        <tr>
                            <td>${exercise.minutes}</td>
                            <td>${exercise.activity}</td>
                            <td><a href="<c:url value='/delete/${exercise.exerciseId}' />" >Delete</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </table>

        </form:form>
```

[image]

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:spring/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/pdfs/**</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/images/**</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

**servlet-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:spring/database.xml"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pluralsight"/>

    <!-- For Static Resources -->   
    <mvc:resources location="assets" mapping="/assets/**"/>
    <mvc:resources location="pdfs" mapping="/pdfs/**"/>


    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="1" />
        <property name="contentNegotiationManager">
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.web.accept.PathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy">
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <map>
                                <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
                                <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
                            </map>
                        </constructor-arg>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </property>

        <property name="defaultViews">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">
                            <property name="autodetectAnnotations" value="true" />
                        </bean>
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" p:paramName="language"/>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver" p:defaultLocale="en"/>

    <bean id="messageSource" 
          class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource" 
          p:basename="messages"></bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" 
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" 
          p:suffix=".jsp" p:order="2"/>

     <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" p:order="0"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: You're sending a GET request. Your method is mapped to the DELETE method.

Comment: Clicking on the link sends a request to `/FitnessTracker/delete/1`. The finam `1` is the exercise ID. So it works fine. What's the problem here? What do you expect the generated HTML code to be, and what does it geneate instead?

Comment: Yeah, and I explained that already: you mapped your controller method with `method = RequestMethod.DELETE`, but you're sending a GET request. So the controller is not called, because no request mapping matches with the request that you're sending.

Comment: What is the spring mvc servlet mapped to? What do the logs say? What is the URL in the address bar before you click the delete link?

Comment: The servlet is mapped to *.html, and other irrelevant mappings. Nothing that matches `/delete/1`.

Comment: Generate a link to "/delete/1.html". And then realize that using a GET to delete is a terrible idea. Anyone could send a link and just clicking on that link would delete the element. Any bot like the google bot indexing your page would delete everything by trying to browse your web site and thus clicking on the links. Use a DELETE using JavaScript, or at least a POST using a form.